# What is the term for an item/entry in a compendium?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

> A **compendium** is a concise, yet comprehensive compilation of a body of knowledge.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compendium)

What then would I call an entry or item of knowledge that is contained by a compendium? Is there a general term for what a compendium is made up of?

Comment: What's wrong with *entry*?

Comment: Nothing, that's what I ended up going with. Was just wondering if there was a term particularly associated with *compendium*.

Comment: oic. Well, with certain types of compendium, @ghoppe's *article* might suit, as might *contribution*. But as you've apparently already realised, there's no special generic word for entries in a compendium as opposed to in any other "unified" package of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would depend on what sort of *compendium* it is.

If it's a compilation of poems, each entry would obviously be a poem. It might be a compendium of books, writings, words, quotations, and any number of things.

The most generic or common term is the one you used: *entry*. I think for compendiums of knowledge the word *article* would also be common.

Comment: Okay thanks - I was just wondering if there was a term specific to compendia but non-specific to whatever was compiled.